# What are the best practices to add jquery to asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I apologize if this question has been asked, but I can't find a question for this anywhere.

I would like to use jquery on my asp.net page, but should I just register a new script? Add a link? Is there some special reference I can add?

[scottgu states](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx) that it's integrated into visual studio, but doesn't describe how to get started adding it to a page?

Comment: You should have it automatically if you're using MVC.  I personally just add it in my webform projects under a script folder and then drag it from there to my master page 'header' so it is on all my pages.

Comment: @WilliamDwyer But how does MVC Accomplish adding it automagically? The way MVC does it is probably a best practice?

Comment: http://appendto.com/community/jquery-vsdoc Check that out too if you want the latest jquery with intellisense.

Comment: Open up a new MVC2/3 project and look at where it puts the files and references the <script src...

Comment: Automagically... Love that, it's in the MVC Templates.  It's not in the standard web form template.

Comment: Google search "adding jquery to webform asp.net" yields this link.. http://css.dzone.com/news/eliminating-postbacks-setting-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't claim to be an expert, but according to my recent research, something like this is best?

```
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQuery", "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js");
```

But [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2552td66.aspx) states

"Call the IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered method to determine whether a client script include with a given key and type pair is already registered and avoid unnecessarily attempting to add the script." it does also mention "The benefit of checking is to reduce unnecessary computation." So, maybe something like this is better:

```
    if (!this.Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("jQuery"))
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQuery", "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js");
    }
```

That seems dumb though, because if I call

```
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQuery", "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js");
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQuery", "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js");
```

It does the same thing as if I just do it once.

Comment: This is an easy and safe way to add it. The possible issues here is if you register script that need jQuery before jQuery, and if you register jQuery two times with different name. What I say here is that you do not have a solution for all case, this is just one way more way. Stackoverflow for example place the jQuery on top and alone, other site is place all javascript including jQuery in one file... Is what are you make... what can you make, what decisions you going to take etc...

Comment: What I've decided to do is wrap this in a method, that can be called from anywhere I might want jQuery: `ScriptRegistration.RegisterJQuery()` Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I can not call them best practice, but some notes:

Add a link is the first think that you can do, if you register it as new script you add extra code to run with out reason.

**Where on page:** jQuery is a core library so load it on top of the page vs the bottom of the page that we left other javascript function to load and use them after the dom ready.

**What version to add and from where ?** You can add the minified version of jQuery, and you can ether load it from your site, ether load it from google. This is also depend if you keep only the jQuery or add it together with other script to a common file.

**What to look for:** In case that you have any conflict with other libraries you can use the jQuery noConflict http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

**Optimize all your script:** If you have more than one script to load, one optimization is to place them all together to a singe file, minified, gzip it, and add it as link to your pages. This is what I do after I follow and all the previous steps.

Comment: While I appreciate all of this information, it doesn't state how to actually add it? Should I register a script? Add a raw html script tag? Add some sort of web javascript reference hocus pokus?

Comment: @McKay I say it, add a raw html script tag. (not register it as script)

Comment: I see the disadvantage of that being that if multiple controls on a page are adding that script tag...

Comment: @McKay correct, if you need to add it this way. In my case I use jQuery on all pages, so I have include it as global and not check every control by him self.

Comment: So, I'm asking about best practices, because at the time I'm writing this, I'm not sure who else will be needing it? Do I need to think about double inclusions each time I reference it? Or should I do a little bit of that at once (see my answer for more discussion on the topic)

Comment: @McKay The best practice is to add all your core script in a file, loaded on top of the page, compress it and minified it, and the second scripts on a second file on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can add jQuery to asp.net by linking the scripts, just link these like you do your other scripts and stylesheets. [unless I missed something]

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way is to reference the jQuery files from [CDNs](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=jquery+cdn).

The difference from manually adding a script tag and Registering in code behind states in your requirements. If you build some custom control which uses jQuery, better to ensure that the scripts references will appear in the page so you'll need to Register from code behind.

If there is a Master page and some javascript which uses jQuery all over the pages, then add it in that Master page.

If the script is used in only a small number of pages, then there is no need to load the scripts in the other 100 pages, so you'll add the  tag only those two or three pages.